# ColdFusion ORM can see table if using native Oracle driver, but not when using thin driver

Tags: oracle, orm, coldfusion, oracle11g, coldfusion-9

On a development server, we have an **Oracle11g** database that's set up and works properly with **ColdFusion ORM** (ColdFusion 9.0.1) using the **native** Oracle driver.

However, on the production system, the driver is not available because we are using the standard edition instead of the enterprise edition. On this server, we're using the **Oracle thin** driver by picking "Other" for the driver type in the ColdFusion administrator -> Data Sources configuration page. It connects properly to the database.

However, after doing so, we now run into this problem whenever we try to run `ormReload()`:

> Table PRODUCTS defined for cfc model.Product does not exist in schema abc.

However, we verified that nothing is wrong with the model and that doing `cfquery` pulls the data from the table just fine. It seems like only the ORM is not finding the table.

The strange thing is that, if we rename the table and clone it:

```
alter table ABC.PRODUCTS rename to PRODUCTS2;
create table ABC.PRODUCTS as select from ABC.PRODUCTS2;
```

This somehow makes CF ORM read the table properly, at least until the CF service is restarted, after which it will repeat the same error.

Does anybody have any idea why this would be happening, and what we can do to fix it?

**Edit:** I managed to find a workaround by creating a synonym:

```
create synonym P for PRODUCTS;
```

And then configuring the persistent component to use the `P` synonym rather than the `PRODUCTS` table, and this seems to fix the issue. However, this doesn't really address the original problem. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

G'day I don't know the precise answer to your question, but can speculate.

Do you perhaps need to specify a different dialect in your ormsettings?  Or perhaps do you need to specify a schema in your component mappings?  Ar your table and your view owned by the same user, in the same schema and stuff like that?  (sorry to sound vague: haven't used Oracle for a while).

Comment: Yes, we've already checked those things many times. To emphasize, without changing anything except the driver, it works perfectly fine using the native Oracle driver, but not with the Oracle thin driver.